# SQL select on multiple conditions in same column

Tags: sql

I want to select the names of US president based on different criteria in the same column 'party'.

What I want to achieve is to select the names of the presidents who served the most years in office for their party. I am able to find the maximum of years per party and select the names of the presidents who served these amount of years but then the criteria won't hold per party. See my code below:

```
select name, party, years_served
from president
where years_served in (select max(years_served) from president group by party)
order by years_served desc
```

Could someone please help me combine the criteria for the parties concering the different maximum years served? Thanks in advance!
[DB Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WihgZ.png)[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcwAt.png)[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uazjK.png)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all help.

Comment: Sorry, new with posting on Stack Overflow, where can I add these?

Comment: Edit your question here itself.

Comment: You can [edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Try the following:

```
select name, party, years_served
from president p
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from president as more_years_in_party
    where more_years_in_party.party=p.party and more_years_in_party.years_served > p.years_served
)
order by years_served desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select name, party, years_served
from president r
where r.years_served = (select max(years_served) from president p where p.party=r.party);
```

It means select the president if he/she has same years_served as maximum in his/her party.
`r` and `p` are just alias

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter by equality of (party, years_served) PAIRS then something like

```
WHERE (party, years_served) IN (SELECT party, max(...) FROM  ...)
```

is what you need, but your engine may not support such syntax.  However, the above is the equivalent of a plain simple join therefore

```
select name, party, years_served
from president
natural join
(select party, max(years_served) as years_served from president group by party)
```

ought to do it.